# Port forwarding from AWS EC2 to RDS(postgres) instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am trying to ssh into rds through ec2, at the moment I can ssh into EC2 instance using putty, but what I would like to achieve here is ssh from ec2 to rds instance using tunneling so that I can do CRUD operation, your help is highly appreciated, I know this can be achieved by **port forwarding**, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Could you please explain your requirements in more detail? Are you wanting to connect from your own computer (on the Internet) to the Amazon RDS instance that is in a private subnet? Why did you tag your question with `amazon-ecs`? Are the CRUD operations manual (in an SQL client) or are you talking about making a permanent connection to perform operations on the database? Feel free to edit your question to clarify exactly what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

RDS is managed service so you can't connect via ssh to it any way. RDS don't provide such feature.

Comment: You cannot connect via SSH but you could connect via the mysql command line tools: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html

Comment: Ssh is not ssl :) @CoryBurke

Comment: The original poster was asking how to SSH to RDS to perform CRUD operations. You can still perform CRUD operations from the command-line. I was trying provide an alternative to your answer, which simply stated it was not possible to SSH. While your answer is technically correct, it isn't that helpful.